# How to boot OS X with network devices in promiscuous mode?

Tags: macos, wifi, startup, ethernet

As OSX no longer allows `ifconfig en0 promisc` and sees that as a bad value and does not set the device flag, what other options are there? I'd like to be able to boot and have both my Airport/WiFi as well as any ethernet/thunderbolt/usb ethernet devices come up in promiscuous mode automatically before login...at boot.

I see that upon running `tshark`/`wireshark`/`tcpdump` etc within the system puts the devices in promiscuous mode as seen from an `ifconfig` `promisc` flag under whatever device I'm capturing.

How can I acheive promiscuous mode on boot? I need this for testing specific login issues at the login window for 802.1x Cisco ISE. Any further information on the matter is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD that starts a capture. It does get the Airport device to be put in promisc mode, but that doesn't help me. I don't want to begin a capture. And I'd also like a solution to have both Airport/WiFi and any/all ethernet/thunderbolt/usb ethernet devices to be in promiscuous mode on boot, before login....ie: the first time the devices come up.

Comment: For that you would write a little script to start at boot !

Comment: My comment was based on you only mentioning the en0 in your question, so maybe you need to expand that.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD but I don't want a capture running continuously. Your solution starts a capture. I only want the device in promiscuous mode, I don't want a capture running. My question states "I'd like to be able to boot and have both my Airport/WiFi as well as any ethernet/thunderbolt/usb ethernet devices come up in promiscuous mode automatically before login...at boot."